# Add Google autocomplete to Google search bar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating a homepage for myself with websites that I like etc.  It also includes a google search bar in the middle of the page.

```html
<form id="googleSearch" method="get" action="https://www.google.com/search">
  <input id="googleSearchBar" type="text" name="q" size="31" value="">
</form>
```

Is there any way that I can add Google's autocomplete to this search bar?

Answer (score 1):

You can make a *GET* request to the following URL:

http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?client=chrome&q=cats

Where "client" param is your browser's name (works with most but you may pass the same type disregarding what the user is currently on and it will still work).

And "q" param is your search string.

This will return  you a list of suggested items which you can then put into a jQuery autocomplete plugin or build your own (you can't just get the whole google dropdown interface to popup with a single function sadly :) )

Answer (score 0):

Google offers an API to implement your own [Custom Search Engine (CSE)](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/tutorial/introduction) for this purpose. See [this page](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/tutorial/autocomplete) for an example which solves exactly your issue.