# "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource." when making "GET" request

Tags: javascript, xml, request, cors, http-headers

I'm using an HTTP-request in order to get Google's autocomplete suggestions, here's what inspired me to do so:

> You can make a GET request to the following URL:
>
> http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?client=chrome&q=cats
>
> Where "client" param is your browser's name (works with most but you may pass >the same type disregarding what the user is currently on and it will still work).
>
> And "q" param is your search string.
>
> This will return you a list of suggested items which you can then put into a jQuery autocomplete plugin or build your own (you can't just get the whole >google dropdown interface to popup with a single function sadly :) )

(src: [Add Google autocomplete to Google search bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41915398/add-google-autocomplete-to-google-search-bar?rq=1))

I'm using this function to get Google's response text:

```
function httpGetAsync(theUrl, getGoogle){
   var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() { 
      if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200)
         getGoogle(xmlHttp.responseText);
   }
   xmlHttp.open("GET", theUrl, true); // true for asynchronous
   xmlHttp.send(null);
}
```

However, when the funtion is executed, CORS seems to prevent me from getting a response: `Failed to load http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?client=chrome&q=xx: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.`

Is there a way of adding an 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header to the resource?

Comment: is your theUrl being served by a web server?

Comment: maybe `http://suggestqueries.google.com` doesn't let you make requests from a client (browser) only a server (a server) - that's why it doesn't send `Access-Control-Allow-*` headers

Answer (score 2):

You cannot make a request to another domain from the users browser, unless the source has the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header for your domain. In conclusion, you cannot make the request on the users part without using some kind of proxy, like this one:

```
https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/
```

Example:

```
url: https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://google.com
```

Comment: Thank you so much, are there any major security issues associated with this method?