# How do i make a fetch request to get search queries from suggestqueries.google.com, or get google suggestions in any other way?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, xmlhttprequest, fetch

[image]

I have a simple Vue.JS new tab page. I'd like to get google suggestions on my search bar, and doing some digging around I found an API where I can do it from. However, when running my code:

```js
function retrieveQueries() {
    fetch(
        `http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?client=chrome&q=cats`
    )
        .then((res) => res.json()) //failed when just printing res as the default output, or with res.text()
        .then((data) => {
            console.log(data);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.error(err);
        });
}
```

However, when executed, the console returns this error message:

```
GoogleSearchBar.vue?69f5:42 TypeError: Failed to fetch
eval @ GoogleSearchBar.vue?69f5:42
Promise.catch (async)
retrieveQueries @ GoogleSearchBar.vue?69f5:40
Object.onInput._cache.<computed>._cache.<computed> @ GoogleSearchBar.vue?69f5:14
callWithErrorHandling @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:154
callWithAsyncErrorHandling @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:163
invoker @ runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js?830f:301
```

But when using an API Tester, it returns this:

```
["cats",["cats","cats for sale","cats for sale in my area","cats for sale UK"],["","","",""],[],{"google:clientdata":{"bpc":false,"tlw":false},"google:suggestrelevance":[1252,650,601,600],"google:suggestsubtypes":[[433,355],[433,457],[402],[402]],"google:suggesttype":["QUERY","QUERY","QUERY","QUERY"],"google:verbatimrelevance":1300}]
```

This code works perfectly fine with the [openweathermap](https://openweathermap.com) API, and when using an [API tester](https://apitester.com/), it seems to return what I am trying to get.

Have I done anything wrong, or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource." when making "GET" request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51171702/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource)

Comment: tl;dr `suggestqueries.google.com` doesn't allow CORS so you either have to make the request from the backend, find an API that does allow CORS, or use something like [corsanywhere](http://corsanywhere.herokuapp.com).

Comment: using corsanywhere solved it for me, thaks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't make a request to another domain from the user's browser, unless the source has the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header for your domain.
This can be bypassed by using a proxy, I used [corsanywhere.](https://corsanywhere.herokuapp.com/)
Input looks like this:

```
https://corsanywhere.herokuapp.com/http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?client=chrome&q=cats
```

my new code was my original with this new link. I can access all of the data now.
(credit to aplet123)